# How to return nested List in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have two classes `ShoppingCart` and `CartItems` like this:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CartItem> Items { get; set; }
}

 public class CartItem
 {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }}
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
        public Guid ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
}
```

I want get all `CartItems` by `ownerId` using this method:

```
public IEnumerable<CartItem> GetCartItems(Guid ownerId)
{
    return _shoppingCarts.Where(row => row.OwnerId == ownerId)
                         .Select(row => row.Items)
                         .ToList() ; 
}
```

but it returns an error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CartItem>>'to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CartItem>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current return value of your method is of type `IEnumerable<List<CartItem>>`.

Instead of `Select` you should use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CartItem> GetCartItems(Guid ownerId)
{
    return _shoppingCarts.Where(row => row.OwnerId == ownerId).SelectMany(row => row.Items).ToList() ; 
}
```

`SelectMany` flattens the collection of collections of `CartItem` to one collection of `CartItem`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You forgot to add **virtual** to your ICollection of CartItems. Now when you load a shoppingCart, you can do:

```
var shoppingCart = _shoppingCarts.Include("CartItems").Where(cart => cart.Id == id);
```

So, to filter for ownerId, you can rewrite your query correspondingly. Just remember to **include** the items.

Comment: I dont need `shoppingCart Entity` , I want get collection Of `CartItem` without `ShoppingCart`

Comment: Even easier. Just make sure your CartItems are part of your Context class, so you can query on them directly